# PHP : Retrive data from a set of arrays

Tags: php

I have a set of data that looks like this

```
 object(stdClass)#5 (39) { ["id"]=> int(125273716) ["status"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (18) { ["retweeted"]=> ["text"]=> string(28) "1234567" } ["is_translator"]=> bool(false)}
```

How can I get the **["text"]**? **I've removed some parts of the data because it's too long. All I want is the ['text'] parameter**. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Function to Convert stdClass Objects to Multidimensional Arrays**

```
<?php

    function objectToArray($d) {
        if (is_object($d)) {
            // Gets the properties of the given object
            // with get_object_vars function
            $d = get_object_vars($d);
        }

        if (is_array($d)) {
            /*
            * Return array converted to object
            * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
            * for recursive call
            */
            return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
        }
        else {
            // Return array
            return $d;
        }
    }
?>
```

Use:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(objectToArray($object));
echo '</pre>';
```

Source: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$object->status->text
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an Object

```
echo $result->status->text;
```

Answer (score 0):

object(stdClass)#5 (39) { ["id"]=> int(125273716) ["status"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (18) { ["retweeted"]=> ["text"]=> string(28) "1234567" } ["is_translator"]=> bool(false)}

You can try as put $res as

```
$res = $result->status->text;
echo $res;
```